# How to update a field with a varchar + incrementing int

Tags: sql, sql-server

Im trying to update the values in table to have unique values that are in the format 'UNKNOWN' + 0001 the next one would be 'UNKNOWN' + 0002. im runnign into some trouble when trying to update the field.

```
 DECLARE @idtest VARCHAR(15) 
    SET @idtest = '' 
    UPDATE TABLE1 
    SET @idtest = ID = CONVERT(int,'UNKNOWN'+ CAST(@idtest + 1  AS VARCHAR(15))) 
    where ID is null or LTRIM(RTRIM(ID )) = ''
    GO
```

Any suggestions would be great. I Can only use sql that is supported up to 2008 R2.

UPDATE:

```
WITH tempUpdateTable AS (
          SELECT t1.*,
                 ROW_NUMBER() over (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS seqnum
          FROM table1 t1
          WHERE ID IS NULL OR LTRIM(RTRIM(ID)) = ''
        )
        UPDATE tempUpdateTable
        SET ID= 'UNKNOWN' + RIGHT('000' + CAST(seqnum AS VARCHAR(255)), 4);
```

Comment: Do you encounter any error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `row_number()` and an updatable CTE:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t1.*,
             row_number() over (order by (select NULL)) as seqnum
      from table1
      where ID is null or ltrim(trim(ID )) = ''
     )
update toupdate
    set id = 'UNKNOWN' + right('00000000', cast(seqnum as varchar(255)), 8);
```

Comment: Ill be back in the office tomorrow I will try this out,

Comment: This works there was a small error in the sql right only take 2 params here is the adjusted sql that is runs and is modified to the exact requirements see the update in the post

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this:

```
DECLARE @idtest INT 
SET @idtest = 0 
UPDATE TABLE1 WITH( TABLOCKX )
SET @idtest = @idtest + 1,
    ID = 'UNKNOWN'+ RIGHT( '0000' + CAST(@idtest AS VARCHAR(15)) , 4 )
where ID is null or LTRIM(RTRIM(ID )) = ''
WITH( MAXDOP = 1 )
```

This is almost the same as what you had, with the difference being that SQL Server does not support multiple assignments.

Explanation:

- `WITH( TABLOCKX )` - exclusive lock on the table, needed to avoid multiple updates
- `WITH( MAXDOP = 1 )` - Maximum Degree of Parallelism is set to 1. In other words, SQL cannot do any task parallelisation which might lead to the ordering being off.

References:
[SO Quirky Update](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45337678/6305294), [SQLServerCentral Quirky Update](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/68467/)

Comment: Ill be back in the office tomorrow I will try this out,

Comment: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'UNKNOWN1' to data type int. This is what I get when I execute this. Same as before.